# Catch exception in Mathematica without having to run computations twice

Tags: exception, wolfram-mathematica

I have to run a number of `NMinimize` commands on various instances. Some of these runs failed to converge.

I want to identify which ones failed to converge **and** obtain the current solution that Mathematica found.

Searches on other posts suggested using `Check[]`, but it does not return the result once it comes out of the error.

So currently, I have the inefficient implementation as follows:

```
allfit1 = ConstantArray[0,16];
For[i = 1, i <= 16, i++, (
allfit1[[i]] = Check[
                    {0, NMinimize[f[x,data[[i]]], x]}, 
                    {1, NMinimize[f[x,data[[i]]], x]}
                    ] 
)]
```

As you see I am having to execute `NMinimize` twice, which is wasteful and time consuming.

Is there a better way?

Comment: You could probably get better answer in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a minor change: you could store the result in a variable:

```
Block[{res}, 
      Check[{0, res = NMinimize[...]}, {1, res}]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
Table[Reap@Quiet@Check[Sow@NMinimize[f[x, d], x]; 1, 0]~
  Extract~{{1}, {2, 1, 1}}, {d, data}]
```